# Can I hope to learn iOS development on my mid 2009 MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro

13 Inch MBP Mid 2009

2.53 GHz Core 2 Duo

4 GB RAM

GeForce 9400M 256 MB

250GB HDD

I just installed El Capitan on in and it's crawling. I plan on upgrading the ram to 8 GB and slapping an SSD in it but even after that is it realistic for me to do light iOS Dev on it? Should I bite the bullet and buy a new laptop?

Comment: Just replacing the internal HD with a SSD will make a big difference. If the macbook is running OK otherwise, you shouldn't need a new Mac. Our school has been actively replacing HHDs with SSDs for the past year in our fleet of MBPs (of various vintages) and it will extend their useful lifetime another few years. If you want to, you can up the RAM to 8GB, but while the case is open when installing the SSD, consider replacing the battery as well.

Comment: You would see big increase in performance if you upgraded you ram to 8 GB and slapped on an SSD instead of the HDD, but if you have the money and really want to enjoy the experience of learning how to code, I would just bite the bullet ant bought a new retina macbook pro 13", prefferably the mid speced one.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. I have the exact same configuration MacBook Pro, except I added some RAM to it (8 GB total) and installed an SSD. It may not do things at lightning speed, but the configuration is more than enough to work on Xcode. I've been learning it in for the past 2 months, so I know firsthand.

Answer (score 0):

With more RAM and an SSD, that machine should be more than adequate to learn iOS development! Even with Swift, you won't run into massively long compilation times until you get into larger projects (more than a couple of thousand lines of code).